# How to get the hour as a total

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm having a problem. How to get the total hour? The output that's been displaying is not the sum that I've been expecting. Here's the SS so that you guys can get the picture.

[image]

I just need the total hour part. Thank you.

Here's the code for getting the total worked hour.

```
    Dim d1 As DateTime
    Dim d2 As DateTime
    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan
    Dim ts2 As TimeSpan
    Dim ts3 As TimeSpan
    Dim ts4 As TimeSpan
    Dim ts5 As TimeSpan
    Dim ts6 As TimeSpan
    Dim tsFinal As TimeSpan

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn1.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut1.Text)
    ts1 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr1.Text = (ts1.ToString)

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn2.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut2.Text)
    ts2 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr2.Text = (ts2.ToString)

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn3.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut3.Text)
    ts3 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr3.Text = (ts3.ToString)

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn4.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut4.Text)
    ts4 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr4.Text = (ts4.ToString)

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn5.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut5.Text)
    ts5 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr5.Text = (ts5.ToString)

    d1 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeIn6.Text)
    d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtTimeOut6.Text)
    ts6 = d2 - d1
    txtTotalHr6.Text = (ts6.ToString)

    tsFinal = ts1 + ts2 + ts3 + ts4 + ts5 + ts6
    txtTotalWorkHour.Text = tsFinal.ToString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a formatting issue.  The default TimeSpan ToString format is d.hh:mm:ss, where d is days.  So 2:11:03:00 means 2 days, 11 hours, and 3 minutes.  I assume you wanted 59:03:00, meaning 59 hours (24 * 2 + 11), and 3 minutes.  To accomplish that, use the following formatting:

```
txtTotalWorkHour.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", tsFinal.TotalHours, tsFinal.Minutes, tsFinal.Seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function GetTotalTime() As TimeSpan
        Dim count As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero
        For Each x As DataGridViewRow In Table.Rows
            count += TimeSpan.Parse(x.Cells(columnIndex).Value)

        Next
        Return count
End Function


'elsewhere
Dim hrs As Integer = GetTotalTime().Hours
```

Comment: Why use a datagridview? The values are already in a series of textbox.

Comment: I thought you are using datagridview. Replace it with wat you are using

Comment: where you are having textboxes

Comment: What do you mean bro?

Comment: put for loop and make a addition